# How do I get only the query string in a Rails route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am using a route like this

```
match "/v1/:method" => "v1#index"
```

My intention here is capture the name of the api method and then send the request to that method inside the controller.

```
def index
    self.send params[:method], params
end
```

I figured this would send the other parameters as an argument to the method, but it didn't work. So my question is how can I pass the non-method parameters in a query string?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`#query_parameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-query_parameters) does exactly what you want:

```
request.query_parameters
```

It's also the most efficient solution since it doesn't construct a new hash, like the other ones do.

Comment: this only works for GET requests. It's not RESTful, but if you were to use POST requests, this wouldn't work

Answer (score 14):

Stolen from the work of a colleague. I find this a slightly more robust solution, since it will work even if there are changes to the path parameters:

```
params.except(*request.path_parameters.keys)
```

Comment: @ChrisBeck There's an even better way. See my answer.

Comment: Indeed.  Much easier to reason with.

Answer (score 7):

I sort of solved this problem by doing this:

```
params.except("method","action","controller")
```