# payment_state and shipment_state not persisting in spree with custom payment gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I'm implementing a custom payment gateway in Spree 2.2. It's one of those gateways where you redirect to the gateway's own website to take payment, and then the bank redirects back to you with a bunch of get params.

I'm having an issue where the order's payment_state and shipment_state end up as null in the database, despite the fact that they are not null in the order object itself, if I put a `debugger` in the code. Calling `order.save` doesn't seem to help.

I've implemented a dirty hack to workaround it:

```
  # This is a hack - for some reason the payment_state and shipment_state weren't being persisted
  # and where being stored in the database as null. Really the spree checkout process
  # should take care of this and we shouldn't have to set them manually.
  # We must be doing something wrong...
  order.update_attribute :payment_state, 'paid'
  order.update_attribute :shipment_state, 'ready'
```

But I'd really like to know what the actual issue is - why aren't those states being persisted? (I should add, before I call the code above, the values for `order.payment_state` and `order.shipment_state` respectively are `balance_due` and `pending` - but that's another issue. If I can get them to save in any way, that's the main issue.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Full code for my controller and gateway is below.

```
class Spree::CommBankController < Spree::StoreController

  def secure_payment
    order = current_order
    @order_info = 'Espionage Online order ' + order.number

    payment_params = {
      "Title" => 'Espionage Online',
      "vpc_AccessCode" => payment_method.preferred_access_code,
      "vpc_Amount" => (order.total * 100).to_i, # convert to cents
      "vpc_Desc" => @order_info,
      "vpc_MerchTxnRef" => order.number,
      "vpc_Merchant" => payment_method.preferred_merchant_id_no,
      "vpc_OrderInfo" => @order_info,
      "vpc_ReturnURL" => secure_payment_callback_url(payment_method_id: payment_method.id),
    }

    payment_request = ::CommWeb::PaymentRequest.new(payment_params, payment_method.preferred_secure_secret)
    redirect_to payment_request.url
  end

  def secure_payment_callback
    # Next line - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116545/how-do-i-get-only-the-query-string-in-a-rails-route
    order = current_order
    query_params = params.except(*request.path_parameters.keys)
    payment_response = ::CommWeb::PaymentResponse.new(query_params, payment_method.preferred_secure_secret)
    if !secure_hash_matches?(payment_response)
      flash.notice = 'Error with payment - secure hash did not match. Please try again.'
      redirect_to checkout_state_path(order.state)
      return
    end

    payment = order.payments.create!({
      :source => Spree::CommbankCheckout.create({
        :params_hash => payment_response.params.to_s,
        :success => payment_response.success?,
        :desc => payment_response.description,
        :trx_response_code => payment_response.trx_response_code,
        :message => payment_response.message,
      }),
      :amount => order.total,
      :payment_method => payment_method,
      :response_code => payment_response.trx_response_code,
    })

    payment.pend
    if payment_response.success?
      # Set payment to completed after order.next because
      # spree expects at least one incomplete payment to process an order to complete
      order.next!
      payment.complete
      debugger
      # This is a hack - for some reason the payment_state and shipment_state weren't being persisted
      # and where being stored in the database as null. Really the spree checkout process
      # should take care of this and we shouldn't have to set them manually.
      # We must be doing something wrong...
      order.update_attribute :payment_state, 'paid'
      order.update_attribute :shipment_state, 'ready'
    else
      payment.failure
    end

    if order.complete?
      flash.notice = Spree.t(:order_processed_successfully)
      session[:order_id] = nil
      redirect_to completion_route(order)
    else
      flash.notice = 'Error: ' + payment_response.message + '. Please try again.'
      redirect_to checkout_state_path(order.state)
    end
  end

  def secure_hash_matches? payment_response
    payment_response.secure_hash_matches?
  end

  def payment_method
    @payment_method ||= Spree::PaymentMethod.find(params[:payment_method_id])
  end

  def completion_route(order)
    order_path(order)
  end

end
```

and the gateway...

```
# Partly inspired from https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree-adyen (the hosted payment page class)
module Spree
  class Gateway::CommBank < Gateway
    preference :merchant_id_no, :string
    preference :access_code, :string
    preference :secure_secret, :string

    def auto_capture?
      true
    end

    # Spree usually grabs these from a Credit Card object but when using
    # Commbank's 3 Party where we wouldn't keep the credit card object
    # as that's entered outside of the store forms
    def actions
      %w{capture}
    end

    # Indicates whether its possible to void the payment.
    def can_void?(payment)
      !payment.void?
    end

    # Indicates whether its possible to capture the payment
    def can_capture?(payment)
      payment.pending? || payment.checkout?
    end

    def method_type
      'commbank'
    end

    def capture(*args)
      ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response.new(true, "", {}, {})
    end

    def source_required?
      false
    end

    def provider_class
      self.class
    end

    def provider
      self
    end

    def purchase
        # This is normally delegated to the payment, but don't do that. Handle it here.
        # This is a hack copied from the Spree Better Paypal Express gem.
        Class.new do
          def success?; true; end
          def authorization; nil; end
        end.new
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `order.state_changes`. Do they show changes to the two states?

I am encountering the same issue while using "spree-adyen". The `order.state_changes` shows that the `payment_state` and `shipment_state` have changed to ready. However, it doesn't persist in the order. This happens randomly with 10% of the orders. I am currently calling `order.update!` manually on the such order, but would really like to know as well what the issue is.

Also, I am not quite sure if `order.update!` is a good solution, as it executes a lot of queries and can be very expensive.

Comment: Hi Ishaan, I'm having this problem aswell with spree-adyen. All my orders do get completed but have payment_state "balance due". Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Hi Paul me too facing same issue had u solved it. i am using adyen HPP

Answer (score 0):

Umm. So apparently `order.update!` will solve my issue. Woops.

Still, a call to  `order.update!` isn't something I've seen in other Spree Payment Gateway gems (https://github.com/spree-contrib/better_spree_paypal_express or https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree-adyen), so I'd be interested to know if I'm doing something really stupid. (I ended up noticing it in the code of https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-spree/blob/master/app%2Fcontrollers%2Fspree%2Fcoinbase_controller.rb)